# form with enctype="multipart/form-data" is not getting submit by command button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, portlet, websphere-portal

I am building a test application with java6, JSF2.0 on WebSphere Portal 8.0.0.3 to achieve the file upload functionality.

**FileUploadView.xhtml**

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="fileItem1" />
       <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

**FileUploadPortlet.java**

```
class FileUploadPortlet extends com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FaceletPortlet{  
      public  void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse   response) throws PortletException, java.io.IOException {
          boolean  isMultipart = PortletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    try  {  
      if  (isMultipart) {
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        PortletFileUpload upload = new PortletFileUpload(factory);

        List /* FileItem */ items = upload.parseRequest(request);

        Iterator iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
          FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

           if  (item.isFormField()) {
               String name = item.getFieldName();
               String value = item.getString();        


           } else {
           String fileName = item.getName();
           long sizeInBytes = item.getSize();
           System.out.println("FileName is: "+fileName+" Size is: "+sizeInBytes);    

                }
            }
          }
        } catch ( Exception e) {
                System.out.println("SampleFileUploadPortlet.processAction() Error occured");
                e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
    }
```

**portlet.xml**

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>FileUploadView</portlet-name>
    <portlet-class>com.code.FileUploadPortlet</portlet.class>
            ........
</portlet>
```

**FileIploadManagedBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
   @SessionScoped
   public class FileIploadManagedBean{      
       public void submit(){
          System.out.println("Hello i am in managed bean!!");
       }
   }
```

When I am trying to submit the form, I can get the file in processAction method of FileUploadPortlet.java. But my submit method of managed bean is not getting called.

But when I remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from my form. Submit method of managed bean is getting called before processAction method of FileUploadPortlet and file is not visible in this processAction method.

Comment: I think you are missing HttpServletRequestWrapper for wrapping your request in FileUploadPortlet

Comment: @Vikas, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I have found a workaround to achieve my goal but my original question remain unanswered . @BalusC, can you please help me?

Comment: Now I have added two button i.e. button1 and button2 on my view and both are working in a different life cycle. On click of button1 I am sending a request with enctype="multipart/form-data" which is hitting processAction method of FileUploadPortlet.java. Here I am able to get file object and set it to the managedbean object. On click of button2 I am sending a request with default enctype which is hitting the submit method of FileIploadManagedBean.java and here i am able to get the file. But with this approach primefaces requestcontext.getcurrentinstance().execute is not workinig.